# Add custom properties to the pom.properties

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to add custom properties for example build.timestamp, build.environment etc to the default generated pom.properties file and i couldn't find anything on the internet on how to do it or may be since a newbie to maven i didn't understand. Any help would be appreciated.

From pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.dev</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

generated output:

```
 #Created by Apache Maven 3.3.9
 version=1.0
 groupId=org.dev
 artifactId=myproject
```

and i would like something like:

```
 #Created by Apache Maven 3.3.9
 version=1.0
 groupId=org.dev
 artifactId=myproject
 build.timestamp=2019-2-21
 build.environment=dev
```

Comment: you can change that if you really like via maven-archiver configuration which can be configured through maven-jar-plugin etc. See https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/ You can only change the `pom.properties` if you replace it with your own one...which I don't see any requirement ? Can you explain what the issue is? What kind of problem you are trying to solve?